# How to store the index page I came from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In the activeadmin interface I have a paginated index list of many products.
Lets say I am on page=3 and go to the show or edit view of a product. After viewing or editing the product I want to go back the page=3 of my products index.

Is there a way to pass the page (3) I came from into the breadcrumbs, or in an action "back_to_list"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the session values:

```
def index
  session[:last_pages] ||= {}
  session[:last_pages][controller_name] = params[:page] || 1

  @products = Product.scoped.page(session[:last_pages][controller_name])
end
```

You can easily extend it to all your controllers by setting it as a before_filter in your application controller.

Comment: Thanx MrYoshiji. This is a good starting point. Now I just need to get it to work with scopes and filters.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= link_to 'Back', :back %>`.  If you lose your pagination param, you can try [using the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840161/how-implement-the-back-link-to-the-page-from-which-comes-from) to make sure the page is included for the back link.